# Poll for the new additional outlook messages using Outlook Rest API without the notifications subscriptions

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi

I need to poll for the new outlook messages. I do not want to subscribe to the notifications, which needs a Webhook. Is there a Outlook REST API to poll for the new outlook messages without using the notification subscription framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use synchronization, which is currently supported on the `/beta` endpoint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#Synchronizemessages. This allows you to do a full sync then poll to get incremental syncs based on the last sync.